# Qual é a melhor opção de servidor para ecommerce?

Tags: servidor

Estou em dúvidas sobre qual servidor escolher para meu ecommerce, será uma loja muita robusta. Estou em dúvida entre o APACHE e o NGINX. Desde já agradeço o empenho!

Comment: Esta pergunta me parece fora do escopo do site.

Comment: Depende muito de alguns fatores, terá que ser mais específico como linguagem ou especificidades. Mas acredito que os dois citados acima suportam aplicações robustas, veja o custo benefício.